# Bluetooth Low Energy dropping data at 115200 baud?

Tags: serial

I'm transmitting serial data from a sensor on my Arduino simultaneously to my laptop via USB and to a terminal app on my phone via a genuine HM-10 BLE module (onboard a Linksprite BLE Shield).

At 9600 baud, the BLE module was transmitting all of my data to the phone's terminal app without issue. I just figured out how to increase the HM-10 module's baud rate to 115200 (for reference, by sending it an AT+BAUD4 command at 9600 baud from the Arduino IDE console via USB, and then uploading a new sketch to the Arduino with both the USB serial and BLE serial baud rates set to 115200). The data is being received via USB serial flawlessly, but the data received by the terminal app on my phone via BLE appears to be missing chunks of data - and I have to try to connect to it 30+ times to get it to properly connect.

Is 115200 baud too fast to transmit data via BLE? Is there any way to make sure all of the data is properly sent via BLE without slowing the program down too much? 9600 baud is too slow for my application, unfortunately.

I should add that I am using an Arduino M0 pro and the BLE is connected via hardware serial (Serial1) and not SoftwareSerial as would need to be done on the Uno, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did some tests and was not able to reliably receive data at over 9600 baud, even with hardware flow control activated via the AT+FLOW1 command. And even then, if either the BLE module or the phone was moving, data was consistentlydropped.

I ended up implementing an SD data logger instead.

Comment: How quickly are you reading the data from the buffer?